# Elegantly set join table attributes on has_many through: association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails 3.2 app `Users` can create `Collections` of `Articles`. `Collections` and `Articles` are joined by a `has_many through: collections_articles` relationship.

I wish to store the `user_id` in the `collections_articles` join table when an `Article` is added to a `Collection`. (So the app can later show who added an article to a collection). Is there an elegant way to do this?

```
class CollectionsArticle
  collection_id
  article_id
  user_id

  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user
```

When a user adds an article to a collection I'd just like to use the shovel, so:

```
  my_collection.articles << my_article
```

Is there anyway to (elegantly) simultaneously set `user_id` of the join table to `current_user`? Or is the best way just to explicitly create the record in the join table itself:

```
  CollectionsArticle.create(article: @article, collection: @collection, user: current_user)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model layer itself does not have knwoledge of the `current_user`, so you have to pass it in from the controller layer somehow.

The most elegant solution I can come up with is to create an `add_article`-method in the `Collection` model:

```
def add_article(article, by_user)
  self.collection_articles.create(article: article, user: by_user)
end
```

..and call that from the controller

Comment: Thanks for that idea axel!