# Has many through: How to Add record and fill fields in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I have these models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :user_items
  has_many :user_items
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, through: :user_items
  has_many :user_items
end

class UserItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end

create_table "user_items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id",
  t.integer  "item_id",
  t.integer  "amount"
end
```

I'd like to know the best ways to add an item to a user an also set an amount in the join table.

I was doing something like this:

```
user = User.first
item = Item.first
UserItems.create(user: user, item: item, amount: 5)
```

but I don't like it so much, and sometimes it doesn't work properly, because if I run

```
user.items   #=> []
```

I get empty array, it seems like it doesn't get the new changes in DB.

So, is there an easy way to do that? something intuitive like this would be perfect:

```
user.user_items << item, amount: 4
```

---

Ok, so I did this way and it worked:

```
user.user_items.create!(item: item, amount: 5)
```

But This way it didn't:

```
user.user_items << item, amount: 4
```

Now it's more elegant. But I still have the problem about the caching request. If I run user.items. it is still empty. Any idea? I tried with inverse_of and nothing. I would like to avoid reload or some methods like this. I would like to do in a transparent way, if it is possible

Comment: `user.items.reload`? I mean, everything is stored perfectly, `user.items` returns an empty array because of caching.

Comment: I would personally opt for this SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982343/elegantly-set-join-table-attributes-on-has-many-through-association) that would give you all that you need (including setting the amount value). Otherwise, you can still do it in two lines.

Comment: @mudasobwa, yep, that's right, everything is stored perfectly. But I think it isn't a good practice if I have to write `reload`, don't you think? That's why I'm looking for a clean way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: If you want an explicit way of saying “user has 5 items”, you might do `User.first.user_items << [item] * 5` but you’ll still need to call save to make the changes persistent.

Comment: Ok, so I did this way and it worked: 
`user.user_items.create!(item: item, amount: 5)`
But This way it didn't:
`user.user_items << item, amount: 4`

Now it's more elegant. But I still have the problem about the caching request. If I run user.items. it is still empty. Any idea? I tried with inverse_of and nothing.
I would like to avoid reload or some methods like this. I would like to do in a transparent way, if it is possible.

Comment: That’s the egg-chicken problem. Either you want caching or you don’t. You might override `def items; super.reload; end` to disable caching for this particular element, but in general the model has no ability to know that the database content of different table has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like :

```
user = User.first
item = Item.first
user.user_items.create!(item_id: item.id, amount: 5)
```

*or:*

```
user.items.push(items)
```

Comment: I think the first one could work, but how are you setting the amount value in the second one?
Thanks!

Comment: @quin yeah second one will just add items for user without amount.if you want to add amount also `user.user_items.push(item_id: item.id, amount: 5)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
user.user_items.push(item: item, amount: 5)
```

Or if you want to reflect items without pushing new values try this

```
UserItem.create(user: user, item: item, amount: 5)
user.reload
user.items # this will reflect newly loaded values now
```